# How to Automate a job to move the latest file with a sequential file name

Tags: command-line, bash

I have files in a directory all part of a sequential naming structure. I want to automate a job where I can find the latest file in this sequence and copy it over to another directory.

E.g. in /tmp/directory23 there are file names:

```
CEN_01 [Modified date 31/05/2021]
CEN_02 [Modified date 07/06/2021]
CEN_03 [Modified date 14/06/2021]
CEN_04 [Modified date 21/06/2021]
CEN_05 [Modified date 28/06/2021]
CEN_06 [Modified date 05/07/2021]
```

I want to automate a job, where I find the latest modified file CEN_06 and copy the file to a different directory.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Look at `man ls`. The command sequence `last_file=$(ls -t | head -n1)` will assign the file name you need into a shell variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts in your question, so I'll adress them separately. I also don't know how confortable your are with Linux, so please tell me if these guidelines are too blurry.

- *find the latest modified file CEN_06 and copy the file to a different directory* : you should be able to do that using the output of `ls -lt`, and then grabbing the first result. After some search, the following seems to be working : `ls -t | head -n1` (edit: thanks to @FedonKadifeli for this command). To copy a file, the `cp` command is what you are looking for.
- *I want to automate a job* : one way to automate stuff in Linux is to use crontabs. You should be able to do what you want using them. I recommand you read the man on that subject `man 5 crontab`. You basically put in a `.sh` file the commands you want to run, and then crontab will automate it for you at given intervals.

Comment: Why are you using this very long command sequence, while a simple `ls -t | head -n1` could easily do the job?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Even better, because Malo's command tends to print an extra space at the start of the file name.

Comment: ... or use `zsh`, where you don't need to rely on fragile parsing of ls output and instead can use a qualified shell glob like `CEN_*(om[1])`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thanks! This is a lot better. I'll update my far too long command :)