# Automate files with no extension to .txt

Tags: command-line, bash, extension

I need to convert specific files named `GYART01 GYART02 GYART03 GYART04 GYART05` to `GYART01.txt GYART02.txt GYART03.txt GYART04.txt GYART05.txt`.

There are other files in all directories that also do not have extensions. So I want to specifically convert all these `GYART` files to `.txt` files.

How should I do this?

Comment: didn't [your earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350303/how-to-automate-a-job-to-move-the-latest-file-with-a-sequential-file-name) provide the answers you needed?

Comment: Can´t you use wildcards to target only the GYART files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Automate a job to move the latest file with a sequential file name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350303/how-to-automate-a-job-to-move-the-latest-file-with-a-sequential-file-name)

Answer (score 5):

Go to the directory:

```
cd <path>
```

Rename files:

```
find . -type f -name 'GYART*' -exec mv '{}' '{}'.txt \;
```